# Scraping entire page with BeautifulSoup except pictures (that were transformed to symbols)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all meta data from several pages of google patents.  But in output I found a lot of unuseful data which are the images that were transformed into symbols. I would like to eliminate that part and reduce the size of my data. But I can not find the way to do that. Here is an example of the page: https://patents.google.com/patent/DE102012105063A1/en . And here is the part that I am trying to eliminate:

```
    <li itemprop="match" itemscope="" repeat="">\n
    <span itemprop="id">QHMBSVQNZZTUGM-ZWKOTPCHSA-N</span>\n
    <span itemprop="name">Cannabidiol</span>\n
    <span itemprop="domain">Chemical compound</span>\n
    <span itemprop="svg_large">
    data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvb
```

...a lot of symbols now that I want to delete...

```
    dD4KPC9zdmc+Cg==</span>\n
    <span itemprop="svg_small">
    data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvb
```

... here starts a new image

Do smb have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the expected output?

Comment: What exactly do you need from the website?

Comment: @MendelG, expected output is everything except the part "a lot of symbols"

Comment: @bigbounty, I need to get all data except "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvb... ... dD4KPC9zdmc+Cg==</span>\n"

Comment: @AlonaSorochynska why do you want to get *everything EXCEPT images* ? Will you render that HTML in browser or what? Can you share more details as for now your issue is quite unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to extract all embedded svg images from the soup and then get your data. For example:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/DE102012105063A1/en'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# delete all svg images from soup
for svg_image in soup.select('[itemprop="svg_large"], [itemprop="svg_small"]'):
    svg_image.extract()

# extract your desired data from the soup (now without images)
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to extract only images which form of a external .jpg image in the server not embedded base64:

```
for link in soup.select('img[src$=".jpg"]'):
    print(link['src'])
```

Comment: I wish to extract everything EXCEPT images